How to play a mp3 file with PyScript?
I want to play an mp3 file using the HTML  tag like so:
    <audio controls>
      <source id="player" src="sounds//ziege.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>

Playing the mp3 file trough the player UI works of course but not within PyScript:
    <button py-click="play">Play</button>
    <button py-click="pause">Pause</button>
    <button py-click="stop">Stop</button>
    
    <script type="py">
        from pyscript import document, display
        from pyweb import pydom
        from pyodide.ffi import to_js

        # probably not necessary - does not work without the conversion either
        sound = to_js(pydom["#player"][0])
        display(sound)

        def play(event):
            display(sound)
            sound.play()

        def pause(event):
            sound.pause()
            
        def stop(event):
            sound.stop()
    </script>

Hitting any of the buttons just produce an "AttributeError: play"
How can I play an mp3 file through the  player or is there a PyScript module that I have overlooked so far?
I am using PyScript version 3.11.3

Just asking, why would you want to do this with PyScript? If there's a specific reason, I'll look into it, but it's much easier to do this with JavaScript.

I am writing some examples for teaching PyScript in a class and the students should not have to learn JavaScript too if its avoidable

You can't use play() method directly on the DOM element when accessed through PyScript in the way you are attempting. To solve the issue, you need to get the audio element using document.getElementById(). I provide updated code for it.
<audio id="player" controls>
    <source src="sounds/ziege.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<button py-click="play">Play</button>
<button py-click="pause">Pause</button>
<button py-click="stop">Stop</button>

<script type="py">
    from pyscript import document, display
    from pyweb import pydom
    from pyodide.ffi import to_js

    // Here, get emement using getElementById
    sound = document.getElementById("player")

    def play(event):
        sound.play()

    def pause(event):
        sound.pause()

    def stop(event):
        sound.pause()
        sound.currentTime = 0
</script>


I have tried this but it gives me an attribut error too even when accessing a property like currentTime. May be its not doable at all with the PyScript version I am using. If I use the Audio class in JavaScript the play() method of that object does what it should do. I wish I could use the Audio class in PyScript too.

@PeterM., did it still play the audio though?

No, could you check your example too?
